# Using Intel RDRAND in Python 2.7

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, random, rdrand

I want to make use of Intel's RDRAND feature on Windows and generate true random numbers (since Python's random module isn't so random). Is there any API in Python which can access this feature?

I've tried installing the rdrand module mentioned in the comment below, but I keep getting an error. Log: http://pastebin.com/A2Vqsqec

The error seems to be thrown by these lines in rdrand.c:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define USING_GCC 1
#elif __clang__
#define USING_CLANG 1
#else
#error Only support for gcc or clang currently
#error if you port to another compiler, please
#error send back the patch to https://github.com/stillson/rdrand
#endif
```

Why is this happening?

UPDATE: I've checked and made sure that __GNUC__ is defined

Comment: Have look at this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rdrand/0.9.0 Also interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680441/using-the-hardware-rng-from-python

Comment: Thank you. I tried pip installing the rdrand module, but I am getting an error: "rdrand.c: fatal error C1189 - Only support for gcc or clang currently" Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use Python to wrap a C/C++ routine, instead of using the Python implementation of RdRand().  A research paper here (http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/aa7ede/meta;jsessionid=A9DA9DDB925E6522D058F3CEEC7D0B21.ip-10-40-2-120), or non-paywalled version here (https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.02212) recently showed how poor the performance of RdRand() in Python is.  Even so, as the paper mentions, the RdRand and RdSeed instructions are not quite "truly" random...

Hope that helps.

Comment: The links are poor, better links: [Intel® DRNG](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/441_Intel_R__DRNG_Software_Implementation_Guide_final_Aug7.pdf), [Intel® DRNG Software Implementation Guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-digital-random-number-generator-drng-software-implementation-guide) and Wikipedia [RdRand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand).

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need RDRAND for quality randomness. The documentation for the [random](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module states:

> Use [`os.urandom()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom) or [`SystemRandom`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom) if you require a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator.

The documentation for [`os.urandom(n)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom) says:

> Return a string of *n* random bytes suitable for cryptographic use.
>
> This function returns random bytes from an OS-specific randomness source. The returned data should be unpredictable enough for cryptographic applications, though its exact quality depends on the OS implementation. On a UNIX-like system this will query `/dev/urandom`, and on Windows it will use `CryptGenRandom()`.

`SystemRandom` is based on `urandom`.